# How can I create a Line with different colors in android

Tags: android, colors, android-studio, draw

I want to create a line with different colors in two ways like:

### 1. ColorBar ([preview](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100174344/Choice/1.jpg))

Something like a progress bar but with different colors

### 2.Colorful Table ([preview](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100174344/Choice/2.jpg))

Something like a table but with different colors(not different cell background)

I want to for example write some code and say the min and max point of the periods and it show me the period in some color (like red) on a line.

so is there any way that I can draw them in my jar file?(I mean the jar file that is connected to activity like MainActivity.jar)
I use Android Studio v 1.0.2

Thanks for your useful helps:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GradientDrawable`.

```
GradientDrawable rainbow = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT,
            new int[] {Color.RED, Color.MAGENTA, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, Color.RED});
```

The [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html) tell you how to set shape, interpolation between colors, position of colors, etc.

Comment: Thanks I think it's good. but when I use it, it shows me the following error:Error:(9) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Comment: I'm sorry It works but one more question. as u see in the second preview, I want to the two colors that are next to each other be completely different. for example if I define red and blue, I don't want to have even a narrow bar of purple between them. Thanks for your helpful answer.